# JavaScript how to loop number counter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to get the following number counter to start only once scrolled to and then have it loop after 5 or 10 seconds, please assist. I've tried using:

```js
$( '#yourdiv').scroll(function() {
    if ( $(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() <= $(this).outerHeight()){
```

as the scroll to function but had no luck. Please view code below.

```js
const counterAnim = (qSelector, start = 0, end, duration = 8000) => {
 const target = document.querySelector(qSelector);
 let startTimestamp = null;
 const step = (timestamp) => {
  if (!startTimestamp) startTimestamp = timestamp;
  const progress = Math.min((timestamp - startTimestamp) / duration, 1);
  target.innerText = Math.floor(progress * (end - start) + start);
  if (progress < 1) {
   window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
 };
 window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
};
//#endregion - end of - number counter animation

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
 counterAnim("#count1", 0, 10000,8000);
 counterAnim("#count2", 0, 40, 8000);
 counterAnim("#count3", 0, 5, 8000);
});
```

```html
<div class="ohio-heading-sc heading text-left" id="ohio-custom-61aa36a52809a">
<h2 class="title"><span id="count1" class="display-4"></span>+  </h2>
<p class="subtitle">lorem ipsum</p>
</div>

<div class="ohio-heading-sc heading text-left" id="ohio-custom-61aa36a52809a">
<h2 class="title"><span id="count2" class="display-4"></span>+  YEARS</h2>
<p class="subtitle">lorem ipsum</p>
</div>

<div class="ohio-heading-sc heading text-left" id="ohio-custom-61aa36a52809a">
<h2 class="title"><span id="count3" class="display-4"></span>   YEAR</h2>
<p class="subtitle">lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So instead calling the functions inside `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {`, call them inside the `if` in the first snippet. Then, call `setInterval` and call these `counterAnim` functions inside.

Comment: @MoshFeu thanks but I'm super noob to javascript so no idea how to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the 3 animations into one function so you can start them all at once (For nice code, nice to have but you can duplicate the code)
2. Instead of calling `counterAnim` in `DOMContentLoaded`, call it based on the `if` condition you mentioned.
3. Create a boolean variable to identify if the counters already reached to viewport once, because the user can keeps scrolling the page but you want to initiate the interval only once.
4. Once they reached the viewport, start the interval (`setInterval`).

```js
const counterAnim = (qSelector, start = 0, end, duration = 8000) => {
  const target = document.querySelector(qSelector);
  let startTimestamp = null;
  const step = (timestamp) => {
    if (!startTimestamp) startTimestamp = timestamp;
    const progress = Math.min((timestamp - startTimestamp) / duration, 1);
    target.innerText = Math.floor(progress * (end - start) + start);
    if (progress < 1) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
  };
  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
};

const animateTexts = () => {
  counterAnim("#count1", 0, 10000, 8000);
  counterAnim("#count2", 0, 40, 8000);
  counterAnim("#count3", 0, 5, 8000);
}

let initiatedInterval = false;
$('#yourdiv').scroll(function() {
  if ($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() <= $(this).outerHeight()) {
    animateTexts();

    if (!initiatedInterval) {
      initiatedInterval = true;
      // 8,000 - animation time + 10,000 - delay
      setInterval(animateTexts, 18_000);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#yourdiv {
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="yourdiv">
  <div style="height: 500px;">Placeholder with 500px height, please scroll</div>
  <div class="ohio-heading-sc heading text-left" id="ohio-custom-61aa36a52809a">
    <h2 class="title"><span id="count1" class="display-4"></span>+ </h2>
    <p class="subtitle">lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <div class="ohio-heading-sc heading text-left" id="ohio-custom-61aa36a52809a">
    <h2 class="title"><span id="count2" class="display-4"></span>+ YEARS</h2>
    <p class="subtitle">lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <div class="ohio-heading-sc heading text-left" id="ohio-custom-61aa36a52809a">
    <h2 class="title"><span id="count3" class="display-4"></span> YEAR</h2>
    <p class="subtitle">lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I really encourage you to read deeply learn the pieces of code I posted but not just copy / paste them.